# Altering Three Variables in an SQL File Without Explicitly Opening It

Tags: sql, automation, installation, windows-installer, editing

To clarify what my question means and give some context, me and my colleague are working on an msi package (developed using WiX 3.5) that automates the installation and configuration of a terminal with our software. However one point on our tech note indicates that an sql file needs to be opened and changed as per user requirement at the time, so something we cannot hard code in.

Getting the variables we need is no problem, setup can export a settings.ini file or whatever that will hold the values we need, the problem is moving these values directly into an sql file automatically, with as little user interaction as possible. Our client company's workers are not software people, so we need to find a way.

The "SET" parts are the fields that need to be updated on install:

```
DECLARE @Galaxy varchar(32)
SET @Galaxy = 'foo'
DECLARE @IPAddress varchar(15)
SET @IPAddress = 'foo'
DECLARE @Project varchar(32)
SET @Project = 'foo'
```

Any insight would be very helpful, SQL is not my usual area of work.

Comment: How is this SQL file later executed? Might it not be better to investigate whether the executor can already/can be altered to accept the arguments directly?

Comment: Unfortunately out technical lead is on holiday as of today and he neglected to mention this one thing, because I am led to believe this is the last step in the automation - the client will take control after this point. EDIT: I will ask around the office to see if anyone knows, lol

Answer (score 1):

From your requirements I conclude that SQL Server client needs to be installed on each terminal. Thus sqlcmd is available, and you can use the `:setvar` mechanism to set values before executing the script.

See [this example](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/the-sqlcmd-workbench/) where :setvar is used directly in the .sql script. Variables are evaluated using `$(variablename)`. These variables can also be set on the command line ([section Variable Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)), so that no modifications in the .sql file are necessary.